# MpscUnboundedArrayQueue.poll Infinite Loop

Tags: grpc

### now all grpc-default-worker-ELG threads happens below stack：

```
"grpc-default-worker-ELG-1-8" #179 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000fffeccd99000 nid=0x14561 runnable [0x0000fffe339fa000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.shaded.org.jctools.queues.BaseMpscLinkedArrayQueue.poll(BaseMpscLinkedArrayQueue.java:340)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.shaded.org.jctools.queues.MpscUnboundedArrayQueue.poll(MpscUnboundedArrayQueue.java:23)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.pollTaskFrom(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:215)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.pollTask(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:210)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:482)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:384)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None
```

is there any solutions? thank you very much.

Comment: Could you please provide more info? gRPC/netty versions?

Comment: This could be related to this issue: https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/10851.
If so, upgrading to latest gRPC with netty >= 4.1.56.Final should help.